# how to trigger action of different store

Tags: reactjs, redux

im trying to build gmail clone - with categories and emails-of-category, which loads when user clicks the category.
i decided to split the store to 'categoires' and 'emails'

```
export const store = combineReducers({
     categories: categoriesReducer,
     emails: emailsReducer
});
```

categories state looks like this:

```
{
    categories: ["Inbox", "Sent", "Trash", "Spam"],
    selectedCategory: "Inbox",
}
```

emails state looks like this:

```
{
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    emails: [],
    selectedEmails: []
};
```

I feel not convenient with my decision - to trigger 'fetch-emails' of selected category using 'useEffect'
inside one of components:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchEmails(selectedCategory));
}, [dispatch, selectedCategory]);
```

Instead, i think i need somehow to trigger 'fetch-emails' action when selected category changes  from categories store.
Am i right here?
If i do, so how to make it?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think is not correct to do it inside the useEffect, I think that's the correct approach, because the effect is listening when the selectedCategory changes, so it will re run if that condition is met, I would remove the dispatch from the the dependency array, so it won't watch changes of the dispatch function.

Comment: first of all - im happy to hear that you agree with my code!  
But, why i feel it not correct? because i heard that redux purpose - is to make state functionality independent from framework...
I mean - redux can do all logic by itself without need of some additional 'useEffect'

Comment: As a rule, having a change in the store trigger another change in the redux store is considered an anti-pattern (it is not possible in the original Flux pattern). You can probably get the same behavior by having both reducers 'listen' for the action that is triggering the change.

Comment: @happyZZR1400 Your code is fine but I would think selected category is something you'd put on the route and not in the redux store. Running an effect to fetch data when a (usually route parameter) value changes is fine and actually an example in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: Well redux itself is not related to react, but by using the library react-redux, you're already integrating both libraries, for example by just calling a redux hook like useDispatch in your component, the component will be already tied to the react redux library, that means you will need to wrap that component in a redux provider in order to make it work, so honestly I don't think is a big deal doing dispatches in the component, because the reducer will be the one and only responsible to changing the state, not the react component.